# drop rows matching string from an excel file using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have an Excel file `users.xls` cotaining all users from enterprise departments (203 lines) with three lines headers before datas.
I'd like tro drop all users from compta department in the file

i tried to make a script to use pandas to do it
I can list all compta users in file but when i try to drop them, it fails

```py
import pandas as pd

cu = 'users.xls'
users = pd.read_excel(cu, skiprows=3)
sorted_by_username = users.sort_values(['Department'], ascending=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_by_username)

comptausers = df['Department'].str.contains('compta')
dfu = df[comptausers]
print(dfu)
df.drop(index=dfu, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

acutal `users.xls`file:

```sh
cat users.xls  

+--+---------------------+------------ +  
|  |List Of users        |             |  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+  
|  |          |          |             |  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+   
|  |          |          |             |  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+  
|ID|User Name |Department|User Location|  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+  
|2 |smith     |Sales     |Paris        |  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+  
|10|Foo       |Compta    |Paris        |  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+  
|1 |Targaryan |CEO       |London       |  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+  
|21|Cooper    |Compta    |Berlin       |  
+--+----------+-------+--+-------------+
```

What i want:

```sh
cat users.xls  

+--+---------------------+------------ +  
|  |List Of users        |             |  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+  
|  |          |          |             |  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+   
|  |          |          |             |  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+  
|ID|User Name |Department|User Location|  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+  
|2 |smith     |Sales     |Paris        |  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+  
|1 |Targaryan |CEO       |London       |  
+--+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Hi, could you add some code to create a sample of your input dataframe? You can do something like: pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1': [0,1,2], 'col2': [3,4,5]}) but with your columns and sample values.

Comment: `df=df[df['Department']!='Computa']`

Comment: you can handle this a number of ways, the simpliest is to use a .loc to slice your dataframe `df.loc[df['Department'] != 'Computa']`

Comment: thanks for your help. but this doesn't drop rows from file. It just filter them